# No sound on fresh debian 8.9 install

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

I did a fresh install of Debian 8.9, but I am not getting any sound. I get the following error:

```
$ alsactl init
alsactl: init:1758: No soundcards found...
```

I know there is a soundcard because I can see it with `lspci`

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a171] (rev 31)
```

I've tried installing the following firmware packages with no luck:

```
firmware-intel-sound/jessie-backports,now 20161130-3~bpo8+1 all [installed]
firmware-linux/jessie-backports,now 20161130-3~bpo8+1 all [installed]
firmware-linux-free/oldstable,now 3.3 all [installed]
firmware-linux-nonfree/jessie-backports,now 20161130-3~bpo8+1 all [installed]
firmware-misc-nonfree/jessie-backports,now 20161130-3~bpo8+1 all [installed]
firmware-realtek/oldstable,now 0.43 all [installed]
```

### Edit

The following commands don't return anything.

```
lsmod | grep -i audio
lsmod | grep -i snd
dmesg | grep -i audio
dmesg | grep -i snd
```

Comment: `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` what is the output of this command?

Comment: the right hardware module is not loaded. The device is connected (lspci) and you have the firmware. Check with lsmod or dmesg for 'audio', 'snd' strings

Comment: I just updated to Stretch.  Wonder if drivers in Jessie didn't support hardware in my new laptop.